# Multi Linked table navigation - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to show lists which should display after navigating the corresponding fields in the table ,

I am completely clueless on how to accomplish this, I was thinking of multi level drop down menu to accomplish my need, 
But I am not sure how to go through levels on it.

All the contents in the tables are dynamic, 
Here is the information, 
Tables namely District, Municipal , Area and layout

```
District 
| id 
| district_name

Municipal
| id
| district_id
| municipal_name 

Area
| id 
| area_name
| district_id
| municipal_id

Layout
| id 
| layout_name
| district_id
| municipal_id
```

Please guide me to break the logic of this,

Code how I got me to view through first level,

```
<select name="district_option" id="district_option" class="form-control col-sm-6">
            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">------ Select District --------</option>
            @foreach ($districts as $key => $district)
            <option value="{{$district->id}}">{{$district->district_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    <div class="form-group form-inline border p-2">
    {{Form::label('municipal_option', 'District Option ',['class'=>'col-sm-4 h3'])}}


<select name="municipal_option" id="municipal_option" class="form-control col-sm-6">
            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">------ Select District First--------</option>
        </select>
```

!!!!! I would like to show my data here which is mapped to municipal id !!!!

```
 <script>
        $('#district_option').on('change', function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            var municipal_id = e.target.value;
            var BASEURL = "{!! url('admin/engineers/') !!}";
            console.log(municipal_id);
            $.get(BASEURL + '/municipalview?municipal_id=' + municipal_id, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#municipal_option').empty();
                $('#municipal_option').append(
                    '<option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">------ Select District First--------</option>'
                );
                $.each(data, function (index, municipalObj) {
                    $('#municipal_option').append('<option value="' + municipalObj.id + '"> ' +
                        municipalObj.municipal_name + ' </option>');
                })
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Are there any other approaches, I would be happy to explore those too

Comment: Add four selector for each of the tables and then show options dynamically based on value selected in other selector then get the result

Comment: Thanks Sagar for your Prompt response. I only know to populate  results with for selector and not sure to add condition to it. In my case I need to display only the list of municipal names mapped to the district. And for the Area, I would like to show that are mapped under the municipal. If that could be acheived through for, please guide me .

Comment: I've written something similar in my blog. Based on selected category product will be displayed in the another selector. I've made it for two selector. you can extend it up to four for your requirement. Here is the link: http://stacklearning.com/php/laravel/how-to-make-a-dynamic-drop-down-based-on-value-selected-in-another-drop-down-with-laravel-and-jquery/

Comment: Thank you for the info Sagar :)

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Not yet, still figuring out.

Comment: okay, best of luck bro

Comment: If I figure out I will surely add here, you could add to your blog. It would be lot more helpful for newbies. And thanks again for your time :)